# Copy constructor is being called first instead of only move constructor on passing even R-value reference

Tags: c++, string, constructor, copy, move

**Hello! I am making my own string class named strings**

On passing a R-value move constructor and move assignment operator are being called
This is the main function, all i am doing is passing R-value ref, but while debugging only copy are or both move and copy.

```
    int main()
   {
    strings s1="hey!";
       cout<<"\n";
    s1=strings("bye");
       cout<<"\n";
    s1="Hello";
       cout<<"\n";
   strings s2= strings{"Rhythm"};
    s2.print();
    return 0;
   }

   

 //move comstructor
strings::strings(strings &&obj):s{obj.s}
{
  std::cout<<"Calling move const\n";
  obj.s=nullptr;
}
   

 //move assinment operator
   strings& strings::operator=(strings &&obj)
{
    std::cout<<"Using move\n";
    if(this==&obj){
        return *this;
    }
    delete[] s;
    s=obj.s; 
    obj.s=nullptr;
    return *this;
}
       
     //copy constructor;
strings::strings(const strings &obj)
{
   s=new char[strlen(obj.s)+1];
   strcpy(this->s,obj.s);
}
```

[image: The output window]

Comment: Your code does not match your output: which method outputs "using copy" ? Please show the full set of constructors for `strings`. Do you follow the rule of five?

Comment: Also you dont have a constructor that takes a `const char[N]` which you need for the string literals (or `const char*`)

Comment: You know you can copy and paste text even from a Windows cmd shell, right? It's still better than pictures of text.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: My psychic debugging says that you do have a constructor that takes a string literal and _that_ prints out `using copy`.

Comment: Looks like rule of 3/5/0 is broken.. also do you even have  `strings::strings(const char* )` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An moving assignment (not an assignment initialization) requires a move `operator=(strings&&)`. It is not available if you defined own copy constructor. Note, that in situation like this

```
struct S {
    S() {}
    S(const S &obj) {  std::cout << "Copy ctor" << std::endl;}
    S(S &&obj) {  std::cout << "Move ctor" << std::endl;}
    S& operator=(const S &obj) {  std::cout << "Copy =" << std::endl; return *this;}
    S& operator=(S &&obj) {  std::cout << "Move =" << std::endl; return *this;}
};

int main()
{
    S a = S();
    a = S();
}
```

with C++11 compiler the declaration line wouldn't even produce output, because no copy or move did happen, it was elided.

Comment: The declaration actually will produce output in C++11 if copy elision is disabled: https://godbolt.org/z/e1qraj.

Comment: @DanielLangr well we also can use https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/Function-Attributes.html and violate language's rules. As far as I know not all toolchains offer either.

Comment: Yes, an implementation may allow you to violate language rules. But this is not the case. Invocation of move constructor happens according to the standard (if no elided, which is also allowed by the standard).

Comment: Is their a way to "force stop" eliding ?

Comment: @armaanshandilya Not in portable way. programs that rely on the side-effects of copy/move constructors and destructors are not portablem so copy\move operation should be designed in such way it doesn't produce side-effects.

Comment: @armaanshandilya With GCC, you can try ty `-fno-elide-constructors` (note that elision happens even with `-O0`). However, this does not, or course, help since C++17 in cases, where elision is mandatory. (In fact, there is no elision in some cases but deferred temporary materialization mechanism instead — the distinction is subtle but sometimes important. For instance, it works with `std::atomic`, while copy elision does not.)